# How can I vectorize this Sigmoid function?

Tags: java, vectorization

How can this sigmoid function be vectorized? Currently it is using a two-dimensional array.

```
double[][] data = z.getData(); 
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    double[] row = data[i]; 
    for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) { 
        double newVal = 1 / (1 + e.value(data[i][j])); 
        data[i][j] = newVal; 
    } 
}
```